# Editing an event always create new event facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

```
$result = $obj_facebook->api('/'.$model['fb_event_id'].'/events', 'POST', $event_info);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST against event id only, so change:

```
$result = $obj_facebook->api('/'.$model['fb_event_id'].'/events', 'POST', $event_info);
```

to

```
$result = $obj_facebook->api('/'.$model['fb_event_id'], 'POST', $event_info);
```

See here for more:: [FB Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events)